# Creepage points of v notches

Tags: creepage

Why does the creepage between two conductor points be determined separately for V-notches as compared to grooves? Why does it short-circuit in the air the bottom and doesn't go through the whole notch wall? (Image attached)

V notch
[image]

Rectangular notch
[image]

Comment: "Creepage" is conduction through surface contamination. V notches fill with contamination at the bottom; square grooves not so much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the pollution degree ratings for the product you are looking at. The pollution degree will detail the value of "X". Pollution Degree 2 for example has an X value of 1.0mm in most standards. In your first picture, it shows that the creepage distance will jump through air over any value less than or equal to X. In the square notch picture, the value is shown greater than or equal to X so the creepage follows the contour of the material.